# Why is there no exception thrown when trying to change _arr[3]?

Tags: c++

I have this block of code, it is supposed to throw an exception when trying to reach the 3rd index of _arr in Container. It does not throw an exception, I don't understand why.

Removing the constructor causes it to throw an exception, which is really weird.

```
class X {
public:
    X(int x) { std::cout << x - 1; }
};

template <class T, int d=3>
class Container {
    T* _arr;
public:
    Container():_arr(new T[d]){ }
    void setItemAtIndex(T item, int index) { _arr[index] = item; }
    X getItemAtIndex(int index) { return _arr[index]; }
};

int main()
{
    Container<int> container;
    for (int i = 1;i < 4;i++) {
        container.setItemAtIndex(i, i);
        X x = container.getItemAtIndex(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected an exception to be thrown, but it actually outputs "012".

Comment: C++ doesn't check array boundaries. You need to add check code by yourself in `setItemAtIndex` and `getItemAtIndex` methods.

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't throw exceptions. Or at least, it's not an explicit cause. Undefined behavior can do anything in principle.

Comment: Your setItemAtIndex and getItemAtIndex are missing the check to see if index is in range, and if not in range throwing an exception.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I thought changing a memory not allocated specifially to the array (index 3) would be a run-time error, considering that's what I've been experiencing in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ follows the philosophy (although some exceptions violate it) *'don't pay for what you don't need'*. Throwing an exception on exceeding array boundaries would require an explicit check. But if you already *know* that you *cannot* exceed?

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(someArray)/sizeof(*someArray); ++i)
    someArray[i] = 0; // i CANNOT be outside array boundaries, so why check???
```

This makes C++ fast, but on the other hand imposes those checks on *you* if they *are* necessary (just like in your accessor functions). For exactly this reason `std::vector` offers both `operator[]` (unchecked) and `at` (checked, throwing an exception on exceeding current size).

If you access an array out of bounds, you invoke *undefined behaviour*. You might *get away* with, as there might be some additional memory allocated together with your array. If you exceed array bounds *far enough*, you might see right the same 'exception' as when you leave out the constructor (leaving the pointer uninitialised at some random value). Actually, it is not an exception in C++ sense. It is an access violation (reading a memory address not existing or inaccessible to your programme), most likely detected by your operating system, which handles the issue by some appropriate means (e. g. linux sends SIG_SEGV signal to your programme).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Another quick question, aren't access violations supposed to result to a run-time error?

Comment: @tempt Well, it is during execution of your programme when the pointer is read or assigned, isn't it? More over, the pointer's validity might change at any time while your programme executes, how should a compiler detect that? Just that reading from or writing to an invalid address itself is already the error, and yes, a run-time one...

Answer (score 1):

There's no rule in C++ that says an exception must be thrown when accessing an array out of bounds. It's just a case of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

*Removing the constructor causes it to throw an exception, which is really weird*. Undefined behaviour is unpredictable. I guess your system is better set up to catch accesses through uninitialised pointers than out of bounds accesses on arrays.